# Neo4j restore asks for DB upgrade

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have an instance in AWS hosting a Neo4j DB.
The version im using is 2.3.1.
I backed it up using "neo4j-backup".
I then zipped the files and uploaded to an external storage.
I wanted to restore the DB to another instance I have using the same version (2.3.1), so I copied the files to the same folder the 1st instance is using.

When I run the neo4j console command it states:

> ERROR Neo4j cannot be started, because the database files require upgrading and upgrades are disabled in configuration. Please set 'allow_store_upgrade' to 'true' in your configuration file and try again.

Of course the "allow_store_upgrade" is commented out,
Do I have to do the upgrade when restoring?
How can I find the DB version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the same version you shouldn't need to comment it out.  Though I don't think it would harm anything if you do (especially if you still have that backup somewhere else).

You should be able to find the version of Neo4j in the `CHANGES.txt` / `README.txt` files.  It should also output the version in `data/graph.db/messages.log` when you start up the server.  Also if you go to the web console (at `http://localhost:7474` by default) it will show you the version.

Comment: Thanks, but...
When I don't comment out the upgrade I get the following error: Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: '/home/ubuntu/db/neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version ' '. So it does not let me even upgrade the DB.. the DB that is backed up is 2.3.1 (checked the messages.log of the original DB).

Comment: Sorry, I found the issue. I was working on the Staging servers and they contain 2.3.1 but forgot that the Production is still 2.2.5.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out ;)